# Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread" java.lang.​OutOfMemor​yError:Jav​a heap space

Tags: java, matlab

I got this message Err when I tried to open any code in Matlab and I have to restart my computer several time till Matlab works. Is there anybody know what it means!!!!!!!!! Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your matlab and updating you windows with all service packs and patches?. But the subject line what you are telling is nothing to do with your restarts. You have to configure JAVA params to fix memory issue

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the application with less heap space. You will have to config your application with JVM args. Follow the [link](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92813-how-do-i-increase-the-heap-space-for-the-java-vm-in-matlab-6-0-r12-and-later-versions) and you should be fine.